# Xcode - Thread 1: breakpoint 1.5

Tags: xcode

My app has been working perfectly but recently developed this problem which I think is making my app crash! (Don't know but think)Thanks for help in advance. (I'm a beginner)
[Help with the green line please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCM36.png)

Comment: This isn't a crash, it's just LLDB stopping at a breakpoint. Right click on the blue thing on the left, and click "Delete". Then, rerun your project.

Answer (score 0):

It's LLDB stopping at a breakpoint.
Remove that breakpoint just dragging that.
or just disable this icon.

[image: Icon]

After that rerun your project.